HTML Table with Progress Step Header and Highlighted Column
I want to create a HTML table with progress steps row at the top and want to highlight the current progressed column with some border and shadow. Desired output is below-

So far I have only able to highlight the column. But it doesn't work with the header row. Also I need to add shadow effect and the stepper at the top. My current work is here - https://codepen.io/Sawon90/pen/qBwVmBP


table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.header-row {
  background: #e4e4e4;
}

.col-active {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
<colgroup>
  <col></col>
  <col></col>
  <col class="col-active"></col>
  <col></col>
  <col></col>
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="progress-step">Step 1</td>
  <td class="progress-step">Step 2</td>
  <td class="progress-step">Step 3</td>
  <td class="progress-step">Step 4</td>
  <td class="progress-step">Step 5</td>
</tr>
<tr class="header-row">
  <th>First heading</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td>Row 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td>Row 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="header-row">
  <th>Second heading</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 3</td>
  <td>Row 3</td>
  <td>Row 3</td>
  <td>Row 3</td>
  <td>Row 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row 4</td>
  <td>Row 4</td>
  <td>Row 4</td>
  <td>Row 4</td>
  <td>Row 4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>




Your linked to current work is empty and highlights the problem when posting a question that supposes to include work on a 3rd-party site!

Hi @ProfessorAbronsius. I don't know why the link is empty. I have added code there, as well as I have posted the same code in the question. Please ignore the link and consider my code in the question.

HI @ProfessorAbronsius also I have updated the link and use codepen. Please review and help me if you can.

From <col>'s documentation on MDN:

Only a limited number of CSS properties affect <col>:

background (...)
border (...)
visibility (...)
width (...)



What you could do is create a separate element which floats above the table and gets positioned according to the boundingClientRect of the active column, while being completely transparent to pointer events.
Proof of concept.
Note: you'll need to run updateShadow whenever the active column changes.
